Analysis for the peaks in FFT
Suppose I have 2 cases:
1st MOSFET switches with rise times and fall times of around 10ns (Vds).
2nd MOSFET switches with rise times and fall times of around 50ns (Vds).
Both of them have a switching frequency of 100kHz. Since the 1st MOSFET has a higher dv/dt, definitely it will produce more EMI. But how the peak at 100kHz will be decided which in is dB?
Does it have any relation/formula wrt to dv/dt?

10 vs. 50ns switching speed will show a difference above 10MHz, where the break frequency changes.  Consider the Fourier transform, such as here:
Harmonics of a Trapezoidal Waveform Calculator | LearnEMC
Derivation of this is left as an exercise for the student -- starting with a reference such as this, 
https://till.com/articles/QuadTrapVCO/trapezoid.html 
may be useful background.  Note that the breakpoints (rising/falling) must be parameterized, and the changes followed through the integral.
Alternately, one can convolve a square wave with a \$\square(t)\$ function, filtering it to the specified trapezoidal wave.
Extremely little change occurs at the fundamental, as can be seen from the integral.
